# Please assist with HTML script

Tags: html, linux, bash, awk

i am working on creating a script to create html table from input file but script is giving error, please see below script and help.

inputfile.txt

```
Link Status on Sales Server : down : down
Link Status on HR Server : UP : Up5w0d
```

I am using below script to create html table of above input file but getting error.

```
#!/bin/bash

awk -F' : ' '
    BEGIN{
print "<html>
   <head>
      <style>
         table  {
            border-collapse: collapse;
         }
         table th {
            text-align: left;
            background-color: #3a6070;
            color: #FFF;
            padding: 4px 30px 4px 8px;
         }
         table td {
            border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
            padding: 4px 8px;
         }
         table tr:nth-child(odd) td {
            background-color: #e7edf0;
         }


      </style>
   </head>

   <body>
      <h1>Site Status</h1>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Status</th>
                        <th>UPTime</th>
         </tr>"
         }
         {
     print "<tr>"
     for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
       print "<td>" $i "</td>"
     print "</tr>"
  }
  END{
    print "</table></body></html>"
  }
' inputfile.txt > Output.html
```

Comment: "but script is giving error" — And the error message says … what?

Comment: Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Then [edit] your question to improve it (like telling us the problems you have with the shown code, including copy-pasting (as text) the full and complete error messages you might get).

Comment: `awk` doesn't like literal newlines in a string; you'll better use `cat`+heredoc for the static HTML and only use `awk` for generating the table rows.

Comment: Thanks, can i create mentioned script in one line, will it work?

Comment: See [print-block-of-text-to-file-from-awk-script-banner-like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24596514/print-block-of-text-to-file-from-awk-script-banner-like/24597515#24597515)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have multiple line from single `print` use escape sequence `\n` not newline itself, for example

```
awk 'BEGIN{print "abc\ndef"}' emptyfile
```

gives output

```
abc
def
```

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*